# Human Location Tracking

Tags: java, websocket, distributed-computing

I need to write a software project for Human Location Tracking with benefit distributed system components. I need to use web sockets to push information to the server from any computer with coordinates as input. However, I am newbie about `distributed systems`.

Can you suggest me any resource(s) that will help me to gain some info on how I can write that kind of program with using web sockets and java?

I am familiar to java, and the idea behind the distribution systems; but never developed any program for it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[Use a python websockets client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/0.13.0).  If you're pushing information to the server, you are the client.

Then your code can be quite simple, something like this:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://someserver.com/")
print "Sending GPS data..."
ws.send(niftyGPSdataThatYouProvide)
print "Sent!"
result =  ws.recv()
print "Received '%s' from server" % result
ws.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but I think I need some documantation to cover idea

Comment: To cover which idea?   Using websockets?  Sending data to the server?

Comment: Idea is simply; pushing data to server by using web sockets